# How to Change Value of Provider in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have this practice code that uses Context and Memo Hooks API

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-ganguly-4si5s)

Here is a code snippet

```
export const InputContext = createContext()

export const ParentProvider = ({ initialValues, children }) => {
    console.log(initialValues)
    const [values, setValues ] = useState(initialValues);
    const value = {
        values,
        setValues
    }
    return <InputContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</InputContext.Provider>
}
```

What I want is to update the value of array that holds indicators using Context API after I click edit.

The problem is that I can't access the Context after accessing through the memo

Comment: content of the ParentProvider.js looks empty in codesandbox.

Comment: Parent provider in the Sandbox is still empty by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap all components that need access to the context with the provider.  Something like this...

[image: Edit naughty-thunder-msxz1]

---

**ParentProvider.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = [];
export const InputContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const ParentProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[parentprovider.js]::new values", values);
  }, [values]);

  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={{ values, setValues }}>
      {children}
    </InputContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

---

**ShowIndicator.js**

```
import React, { memo, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { InputContext } from "./ParentProvider";

const ShowIndicator = memo(
  ({ name, context }) => {
    const [_name, _setName] = useState(name);
    const [text, setText] = useState();
    const { values, setValues } = useContext(InputContext);

    const editData = e => {
      let newValues = [...values];
      newValues[values.indexOf(_name)] = text;
      setValues(newValues);
      _setName(text);
    };

    const handleTextChange = e => setText(e.target.value);

    const renderDatas = () => {
      return (
        <div key={_name} className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <input
            className="d-flex align-items-center"
            defaultValue={_name}
            onChange={handleTextChange}
          />
          <div>
            <Button
              variant="info"
              style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
              onClick={editData}
            >
              Edit
            </Button>
            <Button variant="dark">Delete</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    return <div style={{ marginBottom: "5px" }}>{renderDatas()}</div>;
  },
  (prev, next) => prev.value === next.value
);

export default ShowIndicator;
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Form, Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import ShowIndicator from "./ShowIndicator";
import { InputContext } from "./ParentProvider";

function App() {
  const [curText, setCurText] = useState("");
  const { values, setValues } = useContext(InputContext);

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!values.includes(curText)) {
      values ? setValues([...values, curText]) : setValues([curText]);
      setCurText("");
    }
  };

  const onChange = e => setCurText(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "10px", textAlign: "center" }}>
        <div>Add Indicator</div>
        <Form inline onSubmit={onSubmit} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
          <Form.Control
            style={{ flex: "1 0 0" }}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={curText}
          />
          <Button type="submit" variant="success">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
        {values &&
          values.map((data, index) => {
            return <ShowIndicator key={index} name={data} />;
          })}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ParentProvider } from "./ParentProvider";

render(
  <ParentProvider>
    <App />
  </ParentProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `useContext` you need to pass the entire `context` object (not only `Consumer`). And just use it like this

```
const Component = () =>{
    const context = useContext(InputContext)
    const { values, setValues } = context

    const handleChange = () => setValues('foo')        

    return(
        <>
            {values}
            <button onClick={handleChange}>Change</button>
        </>
    )
}
```